# asp.net radio button does not post back when page is not valid

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="rdoComm" runat="server" Text="Business Investment" AutoPostBack="true"
        GroupName="selectionType" OnCheckedChanged="rdoComm_CheckedChanged" />
    <asp:RadioButton ID="rdoRes" runat="server" Text="Real Estate" GroupName="selectionType"
        AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="rdoRes_CheckedChanged" />
    <asp:RadioButton ID="rdoBoth" runat="server" Text="Both" GroupName="selectionType"
        AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="rdoBoth_CheckedChanged" />
```

whenever I force validation with "Page_ClientValidate('group')" the radio buttons would not postback, however if I don't use the method I mentioned and leave it to asp.net validation, even if the page is not valid the radio buttons still posts back.

the radio buttons are not meant to post back, but they are meant for hiding and showing controls on the page.

Any ideas?>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should move to a javascript based solution... this would avoid post back and p^rovide a greater experience to the user.

But in case you can't, simply set [`CausesValidation` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.causesvalidation.aspx) to `false` on the radio buttons :

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="rdoComm" runat="server" Text="Business Investment" AutoPostBack="true" CausesValidation="false"
    GroupName="selectionType" OnCheckedChanged="rdoComm_CheckedChanged" />
<asp:RadioButton ID="rdoRes" runat="server" Text="Real Estate" GroupName="selectionType" CausesValidation="false"
    AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="rdoRes_CheckedChanged" />
<asp:RadioButton ID="rdoBoth" runat="server" Text="Both" GroupName="selectionType"
    AutoPostBack="true" CausesValidation="false" OnCheckedChanged="rdoBoth_CheckedChanged" />
```

Comment: thanks steve, causesvalidation doesn't work because in my case page validation is already triggered and the page is not valid. I've tried jquery show and hide but the problem was that validation would still triggers even if the control is hidden.

Comment: I just took care of the validation switching on the page and did a javascript to do the work, turned off auto postback and it worked.